# Is it possible to get the index of foreach in view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

I am doing the CMS, I would like to place the images in different position(I did not use the foreach because the positioning of foreach its either vertical or horizontal). For example i have 4-5 images(So the index will start at 0 until 3/4), the first image/index(which is 0) I would like to place it in the top left, the second image/index(which is 1) I would like to place it in the bottom right etc etc.. Is it possible? If yes how?

Note: I am converting my laravel project into codeigniter, that's why my codes in my view is in the laravel
**View**

```
<div class="fh5co-explore">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-1 animate-box">
                        @if($content[0]['status']=="Activated")
                        <img class="img-resposive" src="assets/images/{{$content[0]['img_jumbotron']}}" alt="work">
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 animate-box">
                        <div class="mt">
                           <div>
                               <?php ?>      
                                <h4><i class="icon-user"></i>{{$textcontent['0']['text_header'] }} ?></h4>
                                <p>{{{ $text[0]['text_description']}}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <h4><i class="icon-video2"></i>{{ $text[1]['text_header'] }}</h4>
                                <p>{{{ $text[1]['text_description']}}}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                    <h4><i class="icon-shield"></i>{{ $text[2]['text_header'] }}</h4>
                                    <p>{{{ $text[1]['text_description']}}}</p>
                                </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: regarding getting index `foreach ($array as $key=>$value){ // $key is the key of each array element respectively `

Comment: Showing some code would be very helpful. What CMS exactly are you working with? In general, as long as you are able to obtain an array of your images or objects, placing them is more of a CSS/jQuery issue rather than CodeIgniter.

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant Sir, i edited my post.. In that code, i tried it in laravel and its working.. The CMS that im exactly working with is editing the content,text message in the index page

Comment: @Anant Can you give me idea how should I call it in view?

Comment: @Angel, I wonder why you have `codeigniter` in your title when you're coding `laravel`. I will leave this for people with more laravel experience, good luck to you.

Comment: I mean sir, I just convert my laravel projects into codeigniter.. I tried that code in my codeigniter and its not working

Comment: Hello Angel, Can you post Screenshot  of laravel o/p and ci view? So that I will get an idea what you're looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think laravel have default template engine so you can free to use the format what you mentioned in your code.But in codeigniter there no any default template engines.But there an alternate way to use the same method in codeigniter by using **Template Parser Class**.To enable this you must include the library call parser,
include this in your codeigniter current controller,

```
$this->load->library('parser');
```

For more information please refer this documentation,

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/parser.html